# Accuracy remains constant at 58%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am creating a CNN-LSTM based model to classify intracranial hemorrhage using CT scan images. I am using a custom data generator that generates x of array shape (512, 512, 3) and y [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU0eO.png)].
This is a binary classification. Based on batch_size, the images will be fed to the entire network and the model will be trained.
Since I am using batch size of 32, x is of shape (32, 30, 512, 512, 3) and y of shape (32, 1), where i am using 30 slice as temporal images.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),  activation='relu'),input_shape=(None,512, 512,3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed((Dropout(0.3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed((Dropout(0.3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed((Dropout(0.3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3)))
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(512,activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer='l2')))  
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

#optim = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              #optimizer= SGD(lr=0.1), #momentum=0.9, decay=0.01),
              optimizer= Adam(lr=0.00001),
              #optimizer= Nadam(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am training the model for 5 epoch but the accuracy seems to be stuck at 58%.
I have created another model using only CNN using the above architecture without the LSTM part and am able to get close to 91% accuracy. When I am including the LSTM part, the accuracy seems to be stagnant but the loss decreases over each epoch as seen below.

```
Epoch 1/5
904/904 [==============================] - 1056s 1s/step - loss: 1.4925 - accuracy: 0.5827 - val_loss: 0.7267 - val_accuracy: 0.5938
Epoch 2/5
904/904 [==============================] - 1050s 1s/step - loss: 0.6946 - accuracy: 0.5837 - val_loss: 0.6776 - val_accuracy: 0.5950
Epoch 3/5
904/904 [==============================] - 1057s 1s/step - loss: 0.6801 - accuracy: 0.5836 - val_loss: 0.6763 - val_accuracy: 0.5944
Epoch 4/5
904/904 [==============================] - 1045s 1s/step - loss: 0.6793 - accuracy: 0.5836 - val_loss: 0.6770 - val_accuracy: 0.5944
Epoch 5/5
904/904 [==============================] - 1048s 1s/step - loss: 0.6794 - accuracy: 0.5836 - val_loss: 0.6745 - val_accuracy: 0.5969
```

[image]

[image]

Below is my data distribution

[image]

What can be the possible reasons here?

Comment: How did you only use a CNN for this probelm? what did you do with the time dimension in that case?

Comment: didnt consider it as a time based data..used each slice as a individual data like we do for any cnn based image classification

Comment: One input data point has size `[30, 512, 512, 3]`, this would require 3D convolution is that what you did?

Comment: I have used 2d convolution where output will be a 2d matrix

Comment: Its unclear what value an LSTM would add, if the goal is classification (for which CNN should be just fine). Secondly, the number of epochs that you've trained for is quite low, try training the network for a few thousand epochs before drawing conclusions. In the initial stages of training, it is unlikely for accuracy & loss to change in lockstep.

Comment: Unless you're using a time sequence (your question doesn't show you are) LSTM probably isn't what you're looking for maybe? Are you trying to predict future hemorrhages?

Answer (score 0):

when you are saying other methods yield better performance , name those. I feel that CNN with LSTM might be tricky...

please check padding , strides and etc.

Adding on a learning rate of .00001 will be very very slow to converge during the course of learning.

Comment: i have tried learning rate from 0.01 till 0.00001. No difference

Comment: i have already mentioned in the question. only using CNN without lstm I am getting better results.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions before one can debug this process -

1. Is your dataset 2D or 3D images?
2. What is the dimension of your image, you have mentioned it before, but what is the dimension when you are using the data in 2D or 3D format?
3. Does your data have any temporal component to it, i.e. is there any relationship between one image and another?

That being said, I think if the individual images in your dataset are uncorrelated to each other, then I do not understand why an LSTM or any kind of recurrent architecture is being used. If you have a 3D dataset then use a 3D convolutional network.
LSTM/RNN is used to model temporal dependencies between your input, for example a sentence when the next word depends on the previous words. In your case, the LSTM is trying to model some relationships between images which do not exist and the information from those 30 (which seems to be the "temporal" dimension) images is being trying to be bottlenecked into the final LSTM timepoint which is being used for classification.